# What is the viscosity of menstruation blood?

Tags: viscosity

I am writing my bachelor thesis about alternative materials for feminine hygiene products and for testing I need to know what the viscosity is of menstruation blood. Can I use water as replacement for menstruation blood because this kind of blood exists out of a big part of water? And what is the composition of menstruation blood in percentages?

Comment: H. Larsson et al., Studies on blood viscosity during the menstrual cycle and in the postmenopausal period in healthy women, *Acta Obstet.Gynecol. Scand.*, **1989**, *68*, 483-486 might be interesting to get a hand on. From the abstract, it seems that for plasma viscosity increases up to day 21 of the menstruation cycle.

Comment: I wonder if menstrual blood viscosity correlates well with circulatory blood viscosity, since the former has to do with shed tissue from the uterine walls rather than blood exposed from a cut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is difficult to give a typical value as the composition and hence the physical properties of menstrual blood varies over the course of a woman's period. [This reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=beenEjKmvPwC&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a good discussion which you may find useful; you can find on p. 159:

> It is fair to say that a large proportion of menses samples are considerably more viscous than blood or water - about four times as viscous as venous blood and 35 times as viscous as water.